# Using subset-sum oracle to determine which numbers are members of the subset

Tags: algorithm

I am having trouble starting off this particular homework problem. Here is the problem:

Suppose that you are given an algorithm as a black box – you cannot see how it is designed – it has the following properties: if you input any sequence of real numbers and an integer k, the algorithm will answer YES or NO indicating whether there is a subset of numbers whose sum is exactly k. Show how to use this black box to find the subset of a given sequence X1, …., Xn whose sum is k. You can use the black box O(n) times.

I figure that the sequence should be sorted first, and anything < k should only be considered. Any help to get started would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, this is NOT subset sum, it uses it.  Will fix your question title.

Comment: You can't sort, as it would distort the sequence (e.g. `4, -2, 1, 1, 0`) has sum 3 in the first three numbers, but `-2, 0, 1, 1, 4` doesn't contain 3 at all.

Comment: @Tawnos: Sub*set*, not sub*sequence*. Sorting doesn't change anything. (huh? no in-word italics?)

Comment: Depending on professor's intent, I may have misread that. I read it as you need to find the portion of the sequence that adds up to `k`. Edit: either way, you can't ignore number > k, because you could have a number that decreases the value of the greater number and is needed to arrive at k. E.g. `-3, 2, 4` while searching for `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is the wrong approach. Think about it this way: how can you use the oracle to determine whether a particular item in the set is part of the sum? Once you know whether that item is part of the sum, how can you use the oracle to figure out whether some other item is part of the sum?

Answer (score -1):

The blackbox is something like this, in C# (ignore that I used int instead of real for the sequence, it's inconsequential to the problem).

```
bool blackbox(List<int> subSequence, int k) 
{
  // unknown
}
```

You are tasked with passing in a subset of the sequence and finding what part of the sequence equals `k`.

Start with the whole sequence, just to see if `k` is in it at all.
Then, if it contains `k`, try a subsequence to see if that subsequence contains `k`. 
Repeat until you have the subsequence that contains `k`.

Comment: `user11235813`, since I'm assuming you downvoted my answer, can you (or whoever did) comment why? The answer is correct for the case that is solvable with O(n) tries. If it is indeed a problem where any set of numbers from the sequence could be used, then you're going to have many more tries than O(n) to find it. E.g. if there are five numbers, and you need 1, 3, and 5, you will have to try the initial full set, then various permutations of that set in order to find the set.

Comment: That was me. I downvoted you because your answer is in terms of subsequences instead of sets, and because if the question *were* about sequences, this would be giving away too much of the solution to the question asker's homework. Also, your comment makes it clear that you don't realize the O(n) solution to the subset version of the problem. It does exist.

Comment: Any answer I think of has contra-examples, but I may be misreading the problem. I mean, it's possible to go one at a time removing elements and checking whether the subset still has the sum (readding and moving to the next should it be necessary), up until you've touched every element, but with the wording of the problem, it looks to me like it wants to find "the subset", rather than "a subset." Typically in uni, such problems wanted the minimum subset. Of course, this problem is already terribly worded, so that shouldn't be too surprising.